# AlarmManager displaying no matter what hour I put

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, dayofweek

I managed to get the code running but it doesn't work properly. I have put an AlarmManager to at an exact hour, display a text, but the thing is that it appears just in the moment I press the input Button, no matter what hour I introduce.

The code:

```
final TimePicker desde = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        int desdeHora = desde.getCurrentHour();
        int desdeMinuto = desde.getCurrentMinute();
        Calendar desde1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        desde1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3); //MIRAR ESTE 1 SIGNIFICA DOMINGO, 2 LUNES, 3 MARTES
        desde1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,desdeHora);
        desde1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,desdeMinuto);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alarma.class);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
           alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmManager.RTC, (desde1.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()) , 604800000, pendingIntent);
```

Sorry if you don't understand something because I'm programming in spanish, ask if you don't understand something.

Comment: Do You really need repeating alarm?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain, I want to repeat it weekly, thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmManager.RTC, (desde1.getTimeInMillis()) , 604800000, pendingIntent);
```

instead of

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmManager.RTC, (desde1.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()) , 604800000, pendingIntent);
```

By the way, what is 604800000 for?

Comment: Yes!!! now it works!! I did not fully understand the function desde1.getTimeInMillis(), but now I do, I really say thank you.

P.D:it is 1000*60*60*24*7, because I want to repeat it every week

Comment: I think the convention is mostly to put in 1000*60*60*24*7 as people will mostly likely recognize what that is. just my 2c